# Disable caching in IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, cache

I'm using IIS 7.5 (full version) on Windows 7 to run PHP \ ASP websites as a development machine and I can't find any way to stop it from caching the static pages of my sites (particularly, the CSS files). I've been searching for a way to do this for a long time and I've tried every answer I've found and none of them actually work. The only thing which does work is restarting the server each time. I'm fairly certain that this is a server side issue for several reasons. The most convincing is that the old CSS file will be served up even for a browser which has never opened the page before. Here is a brief list of the things I've tried:

- I've tried the trick of using `style.css?##########` (where the # represent the modified time-stamp of the file) to link the file.
- I've set the `Cache-Control` response header to `no-cache`.
- I've disabled output caching of CSS files (using both the configuration screen and a web.config file in the site root).
- I've disabled static compression.
- I've used a different extension, `style.css.iis_is_garbage`. Which may (or may not) have worked for cache busting but I found out that my browsers wouldn't play nicely with this before I even tested it.

The only thing I can think of to do now is to either use a different web server or actually write some code in my site to copy the CSS file appending the modified time stamp to the name (while leaving the extension untouched) and pointing the site to that instead of the original file. A different web server will probably be a problem because my company won't use it on their servers. The second solution would probably work (only because it gives IIS no choice) but it would mean adding some fairly pointless code to my site which I'd rather not add (only to later remove it when this goes to prod).

I've found this question repeated on SE several times. Most of those questions do not have an accepted answer. This seems like it **should** be a **very** common use case for IIS yet no one seems to know how to make it happen. Some did have luck with the CSS link parameter cache busting technique but that isn't working for me (even though it is perfectly updating the time stamp each page edit, IIS still serves the old file). So, if you can answer this question in a way that actually works you'll certainly be helping a lot of people.

**Update**

Just to make sure that I am not wrong about this being a server side issue, I've installed a browser that I've never used before (Vivaldi) and, sure enough, it still shows the old content. This is also the third development machine I've setup and all three do the same thing. If it is something I'm doing then I have no idea what it is, I'm using a very basic configuration.  I'm just using the default setup for IIS, VS and Netbeans. I then delete everything from `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` and create two hard links to the VS `Websites` and `NetbeansProject` folders (which are in the users directory).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your bullet points, if you've also done bullets 2 and 3, bullet 1 **will** work, unless it's your browser doing something weird, or given that you've said this is for development, that your development environment is opening a different version or location than you expect.

Comment: I currently have it setup that way and it is not working. I've also been trying many variations of the second point (I've tried setting it server wide and only for one site; I've tried all possible options for it too: leaving both unchecked, specifying that it should prevent caching, specifying that it should cache for 5 seconds, cache based on modification time; I've tried using `.css` and `css` to specify the file type (both seem equivalent here)). None of it works.

Comment: Again: this **does** work. Either triple and quadruple check that it's not your development environment doing something weird, or check that it's not your _browser_ going beyond what the web server is asking of it.  Browsers these days can be very aggressive on their own about caching what they think is static content. Try holding down the shift key as you refresh a page. Most browsers will treat that as indication to ignore or replace cached content.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. These were some of the first things I tried though. See my update, hopefully it'll convince you that I've pretty much ruled out the client. What I have does not work. BTW, I also restart IIS before each test as well.

Comment: It covers a lot of things, but there are still questions about your development environment.